# Replacing particular scriptlet with spring tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm looking for good example, how can I replace this java code with spring tags.

```
<div>
    <%
        Object user = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("User");
        Object role = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("role");
        if(user == null) {
            out.println("<a href=\"register.jsp\">Register</a><a href=\"login.jsp\">Login</a>");
        } else {
            out.println(" Hello  " + user + "  " + "<a href=\"LogoutServlet\" >Logout</a>");
        }   
    %>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <% 
        if (role != null) {
            if(role.equals("admin")) { 
                out.println("<a href=\"adminPanel.jsp\">Admin Panel</a></br>");
                out.println("<a href=\"userOrders\">Orders</a></br>");
            }
        } else {
            if(user != null) 
                out.println("<a href=\"userOrders\">Orders</a></br></br>");
        }
    %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular example core JSTL tags will suffice. However, please make sure that this weird conditional flow is what you expect.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty sessionScope.User}">
        <a href='register.jsp'>Register</a> 
        <a href='login.jsp'>Login</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Hello  <c:out value="sessionScope.User"/>
        <a href='LogoutServlet'>Logout</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<div class="menu">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.role}">
            <c:if test="${sessionScope.role eq 'admin'}">
                <a href='adminPanel.jsp'>Admin Panel</a></br>
                <a href='userOrders'>Orders</a></br>
            </c:if>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.User}">
                <a href='userOrders'>Orders</a></br></br>
            </c:if>
        </c:otherwise>  
    </c:choose>
</div>
```

Please note that `${not empty sessionScope.role}` will evaluate to false in case of empty string. If this is not the desired behavior, use `${sessionScope.role != null}`.

If you consider using Spring Security in your project, writing the similar things would be much easier and nicer with [Spring Security taglib](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html).

Comment: You're using `${not empty sessionScope.User}` when you should be using `${empty sessionScope.User}` and you're not closing the second `<c:when` tag.